# How to enable DEBUG logging on Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am working with [objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) to manage data in google datastore. But in some case i would like to see a debug trail of what happens during my Key lookup or a Query

I am aware of [App Stats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) when deployed to GAE. But, is there a way to enable some sort of `DEBUG` logging on Objectify?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Might you be looking at something like a logger?  enabling [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/) (for Java) or [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/) (for Python) might be a good solution for you. It logs to your console in the devserver, or directly to your admin console in production

Comment: I already have general logging enabled, but unfortunately this does not log the calls to Objectify and subsequent Datastore or Memcache calls. I am able to look at these using AppStats but i was wondering if Objectify library itself provides a way to enable Objectify related debug messages