# High estimated query cost: How to log how objectify breaks down the query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using a query where I load related entities with conditional load groups:

```
@Entity @Cache
public class Result {
    @Load(WithUser.class) @Index private Ref<User> user;
    @Load(WithTile.class) @Index private Ref<Tile> tile;
    @Load(WithLayer.class) private Ref<Layer> layer;
    @Load(WithOverlay.class) private Ref<Overlay> overlay;
    //..
}
```

I realized that query cost is about 100 times higher compared to most other queries that I run. I feel that the cost is too high, as 50 results plus 4x50 getByKey() [which objectify should batch-process] should not be in the CPM_US 0.005 range.

Is it possible to log how objectify breaks down the query and which requests it performs against the datastore in order to reduce cost by writing a more efficient query.

There is a similar question here which hasn't been answered: [How to enable DEBUG logging on Objectify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734278/how-to-enable-debug-logging-on-objectify)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Appengine's provided appstat servlet to explore what is going on in terms of datastore ops.
I think the cleanest way for you to achieve this is:

1. Create a Servlet that executes the query you want to explore
2. Install the appstat servlet using the official instructions here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats
3. Upload to a new version on appengine, call the servlet and then see the appstat stats

an even easier way might be to just try asking Jeff on the official Objectify Google Group; 
He is extremely responsive and has always helped me in the past.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/objectify-appengine

IMPORTANT NOTE: appstats has been raising errors and causing crashes on our server for several reasons, one of them is when log traces are too long - I strongly encourage you to only try it in a controlled staging environment.